# Embedded Neo4j Java Heap out of space when cleaning database

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I got Java Heap out of space when cleaning my Embedded Neo4j database with a following method:

```
public static void cleanDb(Neo4jTemplate template) {
    template.query("MATCH (n) OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r]-() DELETE n,r", null);
}
```

Right now I use following config:

```
GraphDatabaseService graphDb = new GraphDatabaseFactory()
                .newEmbeddedDatabaseBuilder(environment.getProperty(NEO4J_EMBEDDED_DATABASE_PATH_PROPERTY))
                .setConfig(GraphDatabaseSettings.node_keys_indexable, "name,description")
                .setConfig(GraphDatabaseSettings.node_auto_indexing, "true")
                .newGraphDatabase();
```

How to configure Java Heap size for Embedded Neo4j ?

Can I use `setConfig(GraphDatabaseSettings.pagecache_memory, "2g")` for this purpose ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same answer as for your earlier question.

I don't know how it works with Spring Data, but in general you should try to delete nodes/relationships in batches to avoid running out of memory.

Cypher query:

```
MATCH (n)
WITH n LIMIT 10000
OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r]-()
DELETE n, r
RETURN count(n)
```

In your application you do:

```
while return_value > 0:
    run_delete_query()
```

Depending on your memory you can of course increase the `LIMIT`.